# Serializer.is_valid() is always False

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following `Serializer` to handle a user:

```
class FriendSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    login = serializers.CharField(max_length=15, required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=15, required=True)
    mail = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
```

Currently, my view which processes the POST request to register a new user is, based on the Django REST tutorial:

```
 @api_view(['POST'])
    def register_new_user(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            print('POST request !')

            stream = BytesIO(request.body)
            data = JSONParser().parse(stream)

            print(data)

            serializer = FriendSerializer(data=data)

            print(serializer.is_valid())

        else:
            print('Not a POST request!')

        return HttpResponse('Nothing')
```

Thus, to simulate a client with a POST request, I use the following lines:

```
import requests
import json

json_data = json.dumps({'login': 'mylogin', 'password': 'mypassword', 'mail': 'mymail'})
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/register_new_user', json=json_data)
```

However, although the `print(data)` retrieves, as expected,

```
{"login": "mylogin", "mail": "mymail", "password": "mypassword"}
```

The `serializer.is_valid()` always returns `False`.

Am I missing any processing of my request?

**EDIT:**

I got the following info with `serializer.errors`:

```
{'non_field_errors': ['Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str.']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to convert a dictionary to string when using `requests` library's `json` option. This should work:

```
import requests

data = {'login': 'mylogin', 'password': 'mypassword', 'mail': 'mymail'}
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/register_new_user', json=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `ast.literal_eval(request.data)` to convert the string to a dictionary. I use `request.data` instead of manually parsing `request.body`.

However, v1k45's answer is the best solution, as I do not need to convert my dict to a string before sending my request.